# Chrome - No detect Custom protocol if "always open ..." is checked

Tags: google-chrome, custom-protocol

We use a "onBlur" event to detect if our custom protocol is handled on the OS. This works fine, except when we check the question "always open these types of links in the associated apps". If we check, chrome doesn't detect the custom protoicl is handled, it acts as if the custom protocol was not configured.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, increasing time out (protocolcheck.js) works fine.